# Finding the k-th smallest item with quicksort (Python)

Tags: python, algorithm, quicksort

I was trying to implement the algorithm discussed in [this video](https://youtu.be/o1vuCrt7uYc?t=365) and also in [this document](http://algorithmsandme.in/2013/08/find-kth-smallest-element-in-array/).

My quicksort code, which depends on picking **the middle element in the array** as the pivot (see below), as opposed to the approach used by the author of the document above, which uses **the first element in the array** as the pivot as [shown here in the video](https://youtu.be/o1vuCrt7uYc?t=580).

Obviously, my code doesn't work (runs out of the recursion limit eventually). I wonder if it's because of some silly error in my code or that it simply would NOT work as long as I pick the pivot from the middle.

```
def partition(a, start, end):
    # I pick the pivot as the middle item in the array
    # but the algorithm shown in the video seems to
    # pick the first element in the array as pivot
    piv = (start + end) // 2
    pivotVal = a[piv]

    left = start
    right = end

    while left <= right:

        while a[left] < pivotVal:
            left += 1

        while a[right] > pivotVal:
            right -= 1

        if left <= right:
            temp = a[left]
            a[left] = a[right]
            a[right] = temp
            left += 1
            right -= 1

    return left


def quicksort(a, start, end, k):

    if start < end:
        piv = partition(a, start, end)

        if piv == (k - 1):
            print("Found kth smallest: " + piv)
            return a[piv]
        elif piv > (k - 1):
            return quicksort(a, start, piv, k)
        else:
            return quicksort(a, piv + 1, end, k)

myList = [54, 26, 93, 17, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20]
quicksort(myList, 0, len(myList) - 1, 3)
print(myList)
```

Comment: Have you checked quickselect algorithm?

Comment: You're using inclusive array bounds. You're making this needlessly hard. Nearly every algorithm is more elegantly described by using [start, end).

Comment: You are mixing `a` and `arr` in `partition` function.

Comment: @FaizHalde, yes. I did. I just want to try it with a different approach because using quicksort seems more convenient for me to remember the approach.

Comment: @thefourtheye Thank you for pointing this out. I fixed the typo. But that typo is not the problem for the code not working.

Comment: @orlp, if you could elaborate with a concrete example, that'd be great. Thank you.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your code, and also work out an example. Identify where they're going different, and then find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using inclusive array bounds, which isn't the most convenient trick, you'll have to change the range in the recursive calls to `[start, piv - 1]` and `[piv + 1, end]`

Reason being, you are reconsidering the piv element in the each recursion that goes to the left of array.

The code with said changes ran without any stack overflow error.

**EDIT** The output isn't right for few values of k. You may need to check your partition logic again.

Comment: Thank you. I hope someone with a good knowledge of this algorithm (using quicksort to find k-th smallest item) will confirm whether it is possible to pick pivot from the center or not. I have tested my quicksort partition logic on its own without the context of finding k-th element, and it works fine. That is why I decided to ask StackOverflow. Thanks again.

Comment: Middle pivot is definitely possible as I remember reading a resource based on it. I'm sure it will be painfully confusing to implement

Comment: @Faize Halde, Ah...it's a bit reassuring. If you remember the source, please feel free to share. :) Thank you!